# How does Scrapy find Spider class by its name?

Tags: python, scrapy

Say I have This spider:

```
class SomeSPider(Spider):
     name ='spname'
```

Then I can crawl my spider, by creating a new instance of SomeSpider and call the crawler like this for example:

```
spider= SomeSpider()
crawler = Crawler(settings)
crawler.configure()
crawler.crawl(spider)
....
```

Can I Do the same thing using just the spider name? I mean 'spname' ?

```
crawler.crawl('spname') ## I give just the spider name here
```

How to dynamically create the Spider ? 
I guess the scrapy manager do it internally, since this works fine:

```
Scrapy crawl spname
```

One solution, is to parse my spiders folders , get all Spiders classes and filter them using  name attribute? but this looks like a far-fetched solution!

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by @kev answer, here a function that inspect spider class:

```
from scrapy.utils.misc import walk_modules
from scrapy.utils.spider import iter_spider_classes

def _load_spiders(module='spiders.SomeSpider'):
    for module in walk_modules(module):
        for spcls in iter_spider_classes(module):
            self._spiders[spcls.name] = spcls
```

Then you can instantiate :

```
somespider = self._spiders['spname']()
```

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at the source code:

```
# scrapy/commands/crawl.py

class Command(ScrapyCommand):

    def run(self, args, opts):
        ...
```

---

```
# scrapy/spidermanager.py

class SpiderManager(object):

    def _load_spiders(self, module):
        ...

    def create(self, spider_name, **spider_kwargs):
        ...
```

---

```
# scrapy/utils/spider.py

def iter_spider_classes(module):
    """Return an iterator over all spider classes defined in the given module
    that can be instantiated (ie. which have name)
    """
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I am looking in the code `iter_spider_classes(module)` what should I give as a "module" variable here?

Comment: These are some helper functions in `scrapy/utils/misc.py` to load obj dynamically.

Comment: Thank you. I add a solution based on your "read code suggestion"